# how to set equal intervals along boundaries of irregular shaped object in image in python?

Tags: python, opencv, background-subtraction

I'm trying to set equal intervals along the boundary of a black and white image. Is there a way to do it?

I thought about first finding the edge of object using distance transform then scanning the image for the edge. I was thinking of starting with first pixel that is on the edge then find the pixel closest to it, eventually we'll get the list of edge pixels in order. But the runtime of that seems really slow.

Can someone help me with this?

Comment: it helps adding some code to your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can probably use [findCountours](https://docs.opencv.org/3.3.1/d4/d73/tutorial_py_contours_begin.html) for that.

> Each individual contour is a Numpy array of (x,y) coordinates of boundary points of the object.

So you have a list of points on your "boundary". Now you just need to fit consecutive points into a line and calculate which points you want on that line (I'll leave the math of that to you though [:)](https://xkcd.com/541/))

Comment: I get the finding countour part, the problem is that I can't find a way to efficiently fit consecutive points into a line. In my case, there are 18k boundary points, I can't do something like " for each pixel, iterate all other boundary pixels to find the next pixel closest to it". Because that would take really long. I tried restricting the x coordinate to within 1-2 away from current pixel, but my image has background noise that prevents this.

Comment: oh my bad, you right, the boundary points of find contour are in order

Answer (score 0):

You can use morphology (erode or dilate, depends on white or black your blob is). Then find contour. It should be faster than distance transform.

Comment: yeah i think doing an open operation would remove the background noise, but i'm not certain how many times I should apply open operation. If I only do once or twice, the background noise could be too largest to remove. If I did more, the overall details of the captured foreground would be damaged slightly.

Comment: I meant that if you apply erode operation on binary shape, it will give smaller shape, uniformly eaten from boundary. And if you will find contours of these shapes you'll get contours inside your given ones and boundaries will be equally distanced. I did not meant noise reduction. If you need to increase contours, think about dilate operation instead of erode.